# Redux helper function for api requestes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, axios

I'm newbie on react-redux

I have a project where a lot of api request. I handle this with this pattern:

```
import baseUrl from "store/apiConfig.js";
import axios from "axios";
export const START_FETCH = "START_FETCH";
export const SUCCESS_FETCH = "SUCCESS_FETCH";
export const FAILED_FETCH = "FAILED_FETCH";

export const getData = (id) => {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch({ type: START_FETCH });
    let data = {
      id: id
    };
    return axios
      .post(baseUrl + "posts", data, {
        headers: {
          Accept: "application/json",
          "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
      })
      .then(response => {
        dispatch({ type: SUCCESS_FETCH, payload: response.data });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        dispatch({ type: SUCCESS_FAILED, payload: error });
      });
  };
};
```

Now I want to refactoring my project and make it minimize. So there is have someway make all api requests via one helper function. If yes, how?

I imagine it will be like that:

I will dispatch some action from my component and will pass to helper function endpoint and action type like parameter.

Can someone show me some good practice example about that ?

Comment: It is really hard to understand what you are trying to achieve from your question. What does it mean to make all api requests via one helper function? Are you trying to use getData do work with various endpoints other than "posts" and be able to recognise that in Redux store? That would be certainly possible but I am not positive if that is truly your goal or whether I am not understanding you.

Comment: I just make my api requests one function and pass there endpoint eg: posts and request body too parameter so for not writing again some things

Comment: ok let me write a response and you can tell me if I understand you correctly... wait a moment

Comment: I added an answer please mark it as correct if that is what you were looking for or let me know if you need something else ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am working with the assumption that you want to keep the actions START_FETCH, SUCCESS_FETCH and FAILED_FETCH the same. But you want to be changing the endpoint and the request data.

This is how I would write it:

```
import baseUrl from "store/apiConfig.js";
import axios from "axios";
export const START_FETCH = "START_FETCH";
export const SUCCESS_FETCH = "SUCCESS_FETCH";
export const FAILED_FETCH = "FAILED_FETCH";

export const getData = (endpoint, data) => {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch({ type: START_FETCH });
    return axios
      .post(baseUrl + endpoint, data, {
        headers: {
          Accept: "application/json",
          "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
      })
      .then(response => {
        dispatch({ type: SUCCESS_FETCH, payload: response.data });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        dispatch({ type: SUCCESS_FAILED, payload: error });
      });
  };
};

// example call
getData('differentposts', {id:1,other:'some value'}); // return dispatch
```

If you want to indicate in the action what you are changing you can change the dispatches payload to for example:

```
dispatch({ type: SUCCESS_FETCH, payload: {identifier: endpoint, response: response.data} });
```

That would, of course, require you to edit your reducer to handle the dispatch correctly.

Let me know if that answers your question ;)

Comment: With your approach everything look fine. Just i'm confused about SUCCESS_FETCH because i didn't understand how i can send payload to different reducers here. So eg i make request for posts and another request eg. for another data and each data need to be stored in separate reducers and reducers need to identify action type. If all action types will be same how i can send data to different reducers?

Comment: It has to be the same reducer that processes the data differently based on the identifier in a payload depending on your specific use case

Answer (score 0):

I use the following function which has helped me immensely in dealing with error handling,method type and also adding custom headers  when needed using axios as a wrapper.

request.js file

```
import axios from 'axios'
import { BASE_API_URL } from '../constants/apiEndpoints' // https://<api_server>.com

const request = function request(options) {
  const onSuccess = function onSuccess(response) {
    return { data: response.data, headers: response.headers }
  }

  const onError = function onError(error) {
    console.error('API REQUEST FAILED:', error.config)

    if (error.response) {
      // Request was made but server responded with something
      // other than 2xx
      console.error('ERROR STATUS:', error.response.status)
      console.error('ERROR DATA', error.response.data)
      console.error('HEADERS', error.response.headers)
    } else {
      // Something else happened while setting up the request
      // triggered the error
      console.error('ERROR MESSAGE :', error.message)
    }

    return Promise.reject(error.response || error.message)
  }
  const [requestConfig, headers] = options
  const apiConfigs = {
    baseURL: BASE_API_URL
  }
  if (headers) {
    apiConfigs.headers = headers
  }
  const client = axios.create(apiConfigs)
  return client(requestConfig)
    .then(onSuccess)
    .catch(onError)
}

export default request
```

Then I use the function like this

```
const requestOptions = []
requestOptions.push({
        url: `${baseUrl}/posts`
        method: 'PATCH',
        data: <body>
      })
requestOptions.push({ 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' })    // Add this Only if you have headers to add to request
request(requestOptions)
```

Using this your api call using axios  can be reduced to

```
return request([{url:`${baseUrl}/posts`,method:'POST',data:data},{
      Accept: "application/json",
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }]).then((res) => <Your success logic>).catch((err) => <Your error logic>)  // first object in the array to request function is an object with url,method and data key,second object is the headers object.
```